# Adding margin-top causes page to extend

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make the height of the "mainbar" div stretch the entire page without there being a need for the vertical scrollbar while also making sure I can see the top of the div. when I remove the "margin-top" value from the "mainbar" css it removes the scrollbar but cuts off the top 50px. How would I move the div 50px lower (so I can see all of the content inside of it) without extending the page and adding the scrollbar back?

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li class="nav">Home</li>
          <li class="nav">About</li>
          <li class="nav">Upload</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="mainbar">
          <h1>hello</h1>
          <h2>whats up</h2>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Here is the css

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #450068;
  background-color: rgb(69, 0, 104);
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
h1, h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #8729a5;
  border-bottom: .5px solid gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}

.mainbar {
  background-color: #8729a5;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 1100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: .5px solid gray;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem, it seems, is that you have a fixed height for navbar, and want mainbar to take the remainder of the screen.

With mainbar having a height of 100vh it will be as tall as the viewport; so **anything** you do to move it down 50px will cause the scrollbar to appear.  This is the headache of mixing pixel sizes and relative (%, vh/vw) sizes.

If your target browser(s) support modern CSS, a flexbox is the solution to this problem.

If not, the "old way" is to use JavaScript to adjust the size of your mainbar div after the initial CSS-based layout is calculated; a pure CSS solution didn't exist before flexbox.

Comment: Thank you, I changed the height of .navbar to 5vm, .mainbar to 95vh, re-positioned it and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #450068;
  background-color: rgb(69, 0, 104);
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
h1, h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #8729a5;
  border-bottom: .5px solid gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}



 body > .mainbar {
  background-color: #8729a5;
  background-color: black;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 1100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: .5px solid gray;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto
}

new slimScroll(Element);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPEhtml>
<head>
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="slimscroll.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li class="nav">Home</li>
      <li class="nav">About</li>
      <li class="nav">Upload</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="mainbar">
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <h2>whats up</h2>
   <h2>whats up</h2>
 
           
  </div>
</body>
```

Looked at : https://github.com/kamlekar/slim-scroll
and [Hide scroll bar, but still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll)

Not sure if that is what you wanted but the plugin removed the scrollbar on the right of the page >>

Answer (score 0):

Try modifing your CSS maybe it will solve the problem.

`margin-top` to `padding-top` for the `.mainbar`.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #450068;
  background-color: rgb(69, 0, 104);
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
h1, h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #8729a5;
  border-bottom: .5px solid gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}

.mainbar {
  background-color: #8729a5;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 1100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 50px; /* here */
  border: .5px solid gray;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```